# How to UV-Map a complex plane?

Tags: uv

I'm having trouble adding texture to a complex plane object, where can I place the seams so that the UV-Map doesn't appear very distorted and overlapped.

Here is the file [image]

Comment: here is the file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4276" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4276/)

Comment: Please update your question with more detail to describe the issue you're having - preferably with screenshots - so that people can understand your issue without having to download your blend file and make assumptions. This will make it easier for someone to be able to help you while also making the question more accessible to someone else who may be experiencing the same problem.

Comment: @Rich Sedman I "edited" the question so that people can understand my problem better...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, I would separate the pillars from the rest of the mesh, if they are buildings. Otherwise, they are okay.

There are lots of techniques for unwrapping, but here are a few things to keep in mind.

- You can use more than one UV map on an object. For example, you could "project from view, bounds" for the top of the mesh, and use a texture for the ground surface, then unwrap the sides of the pillar on a different map, and use a different texture for that.
- Smart UV unwrap usually does a pretty good job, and you can base your unwrap on that if you want.
- It is not always necessary to unwrap an object, if you want it to be textured. Your best and simplest bet may be to use generated coordinates with box projection.
- You usually want to mark seams on sharp angles, and places that are hard to see, like the bottom of your pillars.

I noticed you are using "Blender Render", not Cycles. Are you sure that is what you want to do? From my knowledge, texturing can be easier in Cycles and many of the tips I suggested only work with Cycles nodes, as far as I know. I don't know very much about Blender render though.

Just some tips, I hope they help. Here is an example of using box projection on your model.

[image]